# Unexpected error while installing typescript

Tags: typescript

I am getting the following error when installing typescript on my windows machine.

PS

```
D:\TypeScript\Ex_Files_TypeScript_EssT\Ex_Files_TypeScript_EssT\Exercise_Files\Chp_01\01_04> npm install -g typescript
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...0","@typescript-eslin'
```

Can somebody help me out on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command solved my problem

npm cache clean --force

npm install -g typescript